# WSO2 AM 2.1.0 to 2.6.0 Migration Issue JMSException

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

While performing WSO2 Migration from 2.1.0 to 2.6.0. I'm getting following issue while running the command: 
`sh wso2server.sh -Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity`

Stacktrace is as follow.

```
[2019-02-25 09:51:10,397]  INFO - JMSTaskManager Reconnection attempt : 4 for Siddhi-JMS-Consumer
[2019-02-25 09:51:15,367]  INFO - JMSTaskManager Reconnection attempt : 5 for Siddhi-JMS-Consumer
[2019-02-25 09:51:15,400]  INFO - JMSTaskManager Reconnection attempt : 4 for Siddhi-JMS-Consumer
[2019-02-25 09:51:20,370]  INFO - JMSTaskManager Reconnection attempt : 5 for Siddhi-JMS-Consumer
[2019-02-25 09:51:20,401]  INFO - JMSTaskManager Reconnection attempt : 4 for Siddhi-JMS-Consumer
[2019-02-25 09:51:20,428] ERROR - JMSTaskManager Error acquiring a JMS connection to : TopicConnectionFactory using JNDI properties : {java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory=amqp://***:***@clientid/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:5672'}
javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection: Unable to Connect
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:346)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:53)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:391)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.createConnection(JMSTaskManager.java:938)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.getConnection(JMSTaskManager.java:817)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.receiveMessage(JMSTaskManager.java:598)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.run(JMSTaskManager.java:521)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionFailureException: Unable to Connect
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:485)
        at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:328)
        ... 10 more
[2019-02-25 09:51:20,433] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.util.ThrottlingRunTimeException
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSTaskManager.handleException(JMSTaskManager.java:1132)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSTaskManager.access$700(JMSTaskManager.java:50)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.createConnection(JMSTaskManager.java:957)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.getConnection(JMSTaskManager.java:817)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.receiveMessage(JMSTaskManager.java:598)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.jms.listener.utils.JMSTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.run(JMSTaskManager.java:521)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-02-25 09:51:20,432]  WARN - AMQStateManager No Waiters for error saving as last error:Exception thrown against AMQConnection:
Host: 172.16.150.189
Port: 5672
Virtual Host: carbon
Client ID: clientid
Active session count: 0: org.wso2.andes.AMQDisconnectedException: Server closed connection and reconnection not permitted.
[2019-02-25 09:51:20,434]  WARN - AMQConnection Throwable Received but no listener set: org.wso2.andes.AMQDisconnectedException: Server closed connection and reconnection not permitted.
```

Along with that I'm also getting error as:

```
[2019-02-25 08:57:10,872] ERROR - ApplicationRegistry org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesException: Connecting to database failed with jndi lookup : WSO2MBStoreDB. data source username : WSO_MIGRATION. SQL Error message : IO Error: Got minus one from a read call
[2019-02-25 08:57:10,873] ERROR - Main Exception during startup. Triggering shutdown
org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesException: Unable to initialise application registry
```

Let me know what I'm missing in it. For migration I'm referring to [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release#210).

Comment: check the admin user credentials in `jndi.properties` file in the <APIM_Home>/repository/conf directory, whether is it correct as per the credentials in `user-mgt.xml` file.